# How to allow WebWorker to call HTTPS URL

Tags: javascript, html, https, web-worker

How I can deal with the CORS policy in Web Worker?
I would like to make an HTTPS call in a worker, but it throws the following CORS exception:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load xxxx Origin localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Maybe I should mention that I'm testing it on a Safari browser

Comment: What kind of exception?

Comment: "XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://xxxx Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. "

Comment: What are the location of the main file, the worker, and the accessed file ?

Comment: the worker is located in "js/worker.js" and the url is a external server..

Comment: Can you make a successful request to that URL without it being in a Web Worker?

Comment: Yes i can and it works fine

Comment: what is your web server kind of?

Comment: Can you test in another browser? It might just be a bug in Safari.

Comment: Yes, it is... I've tested it in Chrome, IE and it works, but in Safari no reaction. / Except for the exception, of course,

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I add my 2 cents in "answer".
It looks like you haven't configured the CORS headers, you can follow the great tutorial here:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

BR,
Saar

Comment: I've already checked and yes it works, but not in a worker and that's the problem.

Does anyone have this perhaps a solution?

Comment: @MasoodMoshref Have you verified that remote server/domain is returning ACAO header and still it is not working in WebWorker?

Comment: See if this is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458104/can-should-html5-web-workers-use-cors-for-cross-origin

Answer (score 0):

With Web Workers, you can inject scripts with [importScripts()](https://w3c.github.io/workers/#dom-workerglobalscope-importscripts). If your server supports JSONP, you could directly make a request like this:

```
importScripts('http://example.com?jsonp=HandleResponse');

function HandleResponse(data) {
  // Do something with the data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your web server type. E.g. in Express.js (node.js) you make it so:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
```

For other web servers see this site: http://enable-cors.org/server.html