# postMessage from child to parent window in Safari using window.open

Tags: javascript, safari, window.open, window.opener, window.parent

I'm using `window.open(...)` to open a completely new window (same domain, same subdomain, same directory, same everything, but a different .html file).  In the child window, I'm using this to send messages back to the parent:

```
window.opener.postMessage({status:'ready'}, window.opener.location);
```

It works great in Chrome and Firefox ... but not in Safari.  Here are some alternatives I tried that did not work:

```
window.opener.* // no matter what I put, Safari says .opener is an empty object
window.parent // child refers to self despite different window, same subdomain
```

How can I get a reference to the parent window so I can send postMessage(...) messages back?

Comment: Have you tried `this.opener`? Is there a variable reference to the opened `window` at `opener`? Can you include full `html`, `javascript` tried at Question?

Comment: Can't provide full files, this comes from production code I shouldn't share.  Does Safari require you to explicitly create a `window` variable?  Not used to this, it's not required in the other browsers I've been working in.  If you take my word for it, there's no explicit (or implicit that I can tell) reassignment of the `window` variable.  But logging `console.log(window.opener)` for example, yields an object of type `Window` with "no properties".

Comment: Have not tried safari. Not sure. By variable mean `var w = window.open("/path/to/resource/")`. `w` references opened `window` at parent `window`.

Comment: _"Can't provide full files, this comes from production code I shouldn't share."_  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without ability to reproduce issue, how can Question be answered accurately?

Comment: A possible alternative approach could be to utilize `SharedWorker` , see [How can I load a shared web worker with a user-script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810002/how-can-i-load-a-shared-web-worker-with-a-user-script/)